# Make Magellan Sidebar Work in Mobile/Move to Bottom of Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

So I have been working with Foundation 5 framework for about a week now and was wondering is there a simple way to have my magellan sidebar move directly to the bottom of the page when viewed on mobile/tablets.

```
<div data-magellan-expedition="fixed">
<div class="large-2 columns right" >
<div id="top">
    <h5>Summary</h5>
    <h4>Business Cards</h4>
</div>

<div id="summary">      
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Digital</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>3.5 * 2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Qty: 50,000 </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>14 Point C2S</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Color Front, Empty Back</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>5 Business day turnaround </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
        <td>5 Business day turnaround </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
        <td>5 Business day turnaround </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
   <h5>Your Price:      $64.5</h5>
   <h5>Unit Cost:      $0.323</h5>
   <a href="#" class="small radius success button">Get Started</a>
</div>  
</div>
</div>
```

also here is a link to the page: http://www.jovincron.in/orderform/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I know there no way to automatic show element on page bottom using Foundation 5 framework when your page is opened on mobile. You would need custom media queries or some JS client check to accomplish this.